# preventDefault() on touchstart without disabling scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touchstart

I use the following script to prevent the first tap on a link:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container a').bind("touchstart",function(e){
        var $link_id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).parent().parent().data('clicked') == $link_id) {
            return true;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Because these links [#container a] are covering the whole screen I am not able to scroll on touch devices.

**Is there a way to keep the scrolling behavior working if the user scrolls** (touchmove / swipe / drag / …)**?**

Maybe there is another way / script to get the effect I want without disabling scrolling…?

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this problem by using [quo.js](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) this library will handle tap event without effecting on scrolling functionality 
the code will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $$('#container a').tap(function(){
     //your function here
 });
});
```